# react native json image

Tags: json, image, react-native

I want to print out JSON images as a variable.

This is my local JSON file (JsonData.json):

```
  {
  "appetizer": [
    {
      "num": "appetizer1",
      "name": "salad",
      "condition": [ "1", "2" ],
      "image": "./appetizer/salad.png"
    },
    {
      "num": "appetizer2",
      "name": "soup",
      "condition": [ "2", "3" ],
      "image": "./appetizer/soup.png"
    },
    …
   ],

  "main": [
    {
      "num": "main1",
      "name": "beef",
      "condition": [ "1" ],
      "image": "./main/beef.png"   
    },
    {
      "num": "main2",
      "name":  "fish",
      "condition": [ "2", "3" ],
      "image": "./main/fish.png"     
    },
   …
  ]
}
```

I filtered the name when condition="2". (salad,soup,fish)

This is the code for filtering name:

```
const newArray1 = [...JsonData["apptizer"], ...JsonData["main"]];
const JsonResult = newArray1.filter(item => {
  if(item.condition.indexOf("2") !== -1) return item.name;
});
```

AND I want to get the image when condition="2".

How can I get them? And How can I print out them?

Do I have to use base64? If so, Can you tell me how to use it?
I saw the explanation, but I can't understand it.

And I imported JSON file this way (I've been correctly using it):

```
var JsonData = require('./JsonData.json');
```

Comment: Do you want `image` and `name` both?

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't matter if it's one code or separated code.

Comment: BTW `image`s are stored locally? It looks like that they will be read from the bundle.

Comment: Yes. I stored images locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
    let mainObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
    let allKeys = Object.keys(mainObject)
    let finalObject = []
    allKeys.map((value, index) => {
        let array = mainObject[value]
        array.map((aryObject, aryIndex) => {
            let condition = aryObject['condition']
            if (condition.includes('2')) {
                finalObject.push(aryObject)
            }
        })
    })
    alert(JSON.stringify(finalObject))
```

You can import data in top of screen:

```
import { data } from './data';
```

You can add below text in **data.js**:

```
export const data = {
    "appetizer": [
        {
            "num": "appetizer1",
            "name": "salad",
            "condition": ["1"],
            "image": "./appetizer/salad.png"
        },
        {
            "num": "appetizer2222",
            "name": "soup",
            "condition": ["2", "3"],
            "image": "./appetizer/soup.png"
        },
    ],
    "main": [
        {
            "num": "main1",
            "name": "beef",
            "condition": ["1"],
            "image": "./main/beef.png"
        },
        {
            "num": "main2",
            "name": "fish",
            "condition": ["21", "3"],
            "image": "./main/fish.png"
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: let mainObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))    <----This error ran into when I insert JsonData at the (data).  (undefined is not an object(evaluating 'condition.includes').   AND This error ran into when I insert JsonData.appitizer at the (data).  (undefined is not an object(undefined is not a function(near '...array.map...')). How to I solve it?

Comment: I parse your data which you added into question.

Comment: You can parse your string into it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I can't understand it. Which string do you mean?

Comment: I am talking about JaonData.json

Comment: let mainObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JsonData.json)). <--- Right? This ran into error too..(JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined").

Comment: You need to parse your data at there. Put your logic for it

Comment: @ello I updated my answer with json file. Kindly take a look on it.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment. <Text>{finalObject[1].name}</Text> is worked well. But, I want to display image in screen. <Image
          style={{something}}
          source={????}
 />
I don't know what to put in the source. Or do I have to do other way?

Comment: You can use     <Image
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          source={{uri: {finalObject[1].name}}}
        />

Comment: source={{uri: {finalObject[1].name}}} <--- This ran into error(SyntaxError : /Users/~~ :Unexpected token, expected,(~:~). And source={{uri: finalObject[1].name}} <--- This was no error. But Image was not displayed. finalObject[1].image, either.

Comment: Then you have a different problem. I think the question which you ask is pretty done with my answer.

Comment: I solved it.  "image": require("./appetizer/soup.png") <---this way in data.js!  Thank you very much for all your comments!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object#values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the arrays corresponding to `appetizer` and `main` and then [Array#flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to extract the nested objects into a transformed array. Then use the `Array#filter` (which you are already using) to filter out only the required objects based on your condition and then [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the `name` and `image` values out of every filtered object into an array of objects.

Please consider following snippts

```js
const jsonData = {"appetizer":[{"num":"appetizer1","name":"salad","condition":["1","2"],"image":"./appetizer/salad.png"},{"num":"appetizer2","name":"soup","condition":["2","3"],"image":"./appetizer/soup.png"}],"main":[{"num":"main1","name":"beef","condition":["1"],"image":"./main/beef.png"},{"num":"main2","name":"fish","condition":["2","3"],"image":"./main/fish.png"}]};

const filteredValues = Object.values(jsonData)
  .flat()
  .filter(o => o.condition.includes('2'))
  .map(({name, image}) => ({ name, image }));

console.log(filteredValues);
```

The output of the above code will be an array of objects having the following structure

```
[{
  "name": SOME_NAME,
  "image": SOME_PATH
 },
 {
  "name": SOME_NAME,
  "image": SOME_PATH
 },
 ...
]
```

You can use the above array to retrieve your `image` path and display it accordingly.

I think you shouldn't be worried about `base64` as images are stored locally and `path` will be sufficient to display the image.

Hope this will help!!!

**Side Note:** You can avoid the `Array#flat` part as you are already doing it manually `[...JsonData["apptizer"], ...JsonData["main"]]` but `flat` will be handy in case there are more keys in `jsonData` that need to be considered.